# Community Connector Logger.log doesn't parse severity field provided in jsonPayload

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, google-cloud-functions, looker-studio, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm **trying to log JSON Objects** from my Google Apps Script - Data Studio Community Connector code **to Stackdriver Logging** as described [in the official doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#processing_special_json_fields_in_messages)

Using `console.log(jsonObject)` the jsonObject is converted to string. It doesn't work.

Using `Logger.log(jsonObject)` instead, the jsonObject y parsed inside de jsonPayload property of the log entry. Good.

But **all log entries are inserted with INFO severity level**.

If I include the severity property inside de jsonObject, ***the severity is not parsed as expected***.

I tried a few options including the severity as string "ERROR" or a number 500 but it doesn't work.

Some examples I tried from my Community Connector Code:

```
Logger.log({
  message: 'This is the message / title for the log entry. Works fine',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  otherData: {
    userId: '459',
    connectorType: 'blahblah',
    includeFilters: true
  }
});
```

OR

```
Logger.log({
  message: 'This is the message / title for the log entry. Works fine',
  severity: 500,
  otherData: {
    userId: '459',
    connectorType: 'blahblah',
    includeFilters: true
  }
});
```

As you can see, the severity property never gets parsed as the severity level.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try using the `severity: enum(500)` format?

Comment: Thanks @FaridShumbar but It doesn't work. enum() is not a function in Google Apps Scripts

Comment: I think that this is common error that stackdriver is having: I have found the same problem trying to log with different levels in Cloud Functions using NodeJS, Cloud Functions using Python and Cloud Run using Python. My best recommendation would be to use the stackdriver client. It is a cumbersome solution, and I only manage to make it work for Python, but it is worth trying (at least if it easy to add in apps-script).